# Not Consistent Result

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

The code I have worked on doesn't work a 100% of the time. I keep having the program try to create multiple integers for one integer in the array. The result is that I need the pin equal to the num. When I run the program sometimes the num is what is printed out and at others times the program decides to not equal what it printed earlier.

For example this the outcome
Pin: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Num: 2 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 1 3
Enter the password
The code is 32345
The password should be 23232

However this answer may or may not work.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Authenticate_TylerD {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    //arrays
    int[] pin = {3, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] num = new int[10];
    int userIn;
    int[] userIn2 = new int [5];

    //Numbers for pin
    System.out.println("Pin: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
    System.out.print("Num: ");

    //shou
    for(int i = 0;i<=9;i++){
            num[i] = (int)(Math.random()*3)+1;
            System.out.print(num[i] + " ");
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(i == pin[j]){
                pin[j] = num[i];
                //System.out.print(num[i] + "<-- RanNum ");
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Enter the password");
    userIn = scan.nextInt();

    for(int i = 4;i>=0;i--){
        userIn2[i] = userIn%10;
        userIn = userIn/10;
        System.out.print(pin[i]);
        System.out.print(userIn2[i]);

        if(userIn2[i] != pin[i]){
            System.out.print("\nIncorrect PIN");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Correct PIN ");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. P.S. There is no rush to answer this, please write back when you have the chance.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve and What is the error you are getting?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and get your first badge

Comment: what do you mean by `Not Consistent Result` ? add that explanation as well.

Comment: @Hemant There are no errors that I have received however the program does not want to use the numbers it had printed out and uses another number instead, but  by random chance it works.